# Stuck on Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the following partial differential equation:

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} + (y+t)\frac{\partial h}{\partial y} + h = 0$$

So far, the only methods I am familiar with solving PDEs are separation of variables, Laplace transforms, Fourier transforms, change of variables, method of characteristics, and a little bit of Fourier series, though I would like a closed form for the solution. I tried using the method of change of variables to solve the PDE and got the following general answer:

$$h(t,y)=ce^{-t}g(t-\ln\left | y+t \right |)$$

However, I don't think this is correct since when I plugged this in, it turned out to not be the solution. Wolfram Alpha gives the answer as:

$$h(t,y) = ce^{-2t}(t+y+1)$$

From the PDEs I've solved before, it seems obvious that this isn't the general solution. I am pretty sure that Wolfram Alpha chose a specific function $g(c)$, where $c$ is a variable of $t$ and $y$, in order to get a certain solution. Either that or Wolfram chose an initial value to apply. How would I get the general solution to this PDE? Any method would be acceptable. From there, how do you get the specific solution that Wolfram Alpha got? Preferably, I would like to avoid solving the following ODE:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}=y+t$$

in the process, since the PDE comes from solving $\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}=y+t$ as an inexact differential equation. If more work is needed to be shown, I will do so without hesitation.

Comment: But $y'=y+t$ is a linear ode. I don't understand why you set up a pde to solve this simple ode.

Comment: @Jacky Chong Because I challenged myself to do it through an inexact differential equation. Very unnecessary, and it is a simple ode to solve, but I like to challenge myself with stuff like this. The context isn't really necessary, I just want to solve this PDE.

Comment: You could solve this equation by inexact differential, but you need to make assumptions on the integrating factor to reduce the problem to an ode.

Comment: @JackyChong if your wondering, I know, I am a weird person.

Comment: @JackyChong what assumption would I have to make? As far as I see, the pde is not separable and change of variables didn't work for me.

Comment: This is very standard. You either assume the integrating factor depends only on $y$ or only on $t$.

Comment: @JackyChong That's why I'm solving the PDE, because none of those integrating factors work.

Comment: check again. This is standard.

Comment: @JackyChong Checked again. It doesn't work. Even if I did something wrong, can we forget the context and try to solve the PDE? I'm just curious about what I'm missing in that certain aspect, I don't care about anything else. Treat it as if only the PDE was given.

Comment: It's easy if I am allowed to solve the ode. But since I am not allowed to solve the ode then I have no clue.

Comment: @JackyChong yeah, I think you're right. I tried with the method of characteristics but it basically gave the original ode. How would you solve it if you were allowed to solve the ode? By that I mean what's your prefered method to solve this pde?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $h$ is a solution your original PDE, then consider
\begin{align}
u(t, y) = e^{t}h(t, y). 
\end{align}
Observe
\begin{align}
u_t = e^{t}h+e^{t}h_t
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
u_y = e^{t}h_y
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
u_t+(t+y)u_y = e^t(h_t+(t+y)h_y+h) =  0.
\end{align}
Hence it suffices to solve 
\begin{align}
u_t+(t+y)u_y = 0.
\end{align}
which is a good old transport equation.

Using the method of characteristics, observe
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}u(t, y(t)) = \partial_t u + y'(t)\partial u_y = u_t+(t+y)u_y =0
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
y' = t+y \ \ \implies \ \ y(t) = (y_0+1)e^{t}-t-1.
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
u(t, (y_0+1)e^{t}-t-1) = \text{ const} = u(0, y_0) = g(y_0) 
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
u(t, y) = g(e^{-t}(y+t+1)-1) \ \ \implies \ \ h(t, y) = e^{-t}g(e^{-t}(y+t+1)-1)
\end{align}

Comment: I didn't realize that $e^{t}h(t,y)$ would be a solution of the PDE. Even though it uses the ode, I realized how to approach a PDE like this. I really tried a lot of things and it didn't work out. Thanks for the post!

Comment: $\begin{align}
y' = t+y \ \ \implies \ \ y(t) = (y_0+1)e^{t}-t-1.
\end{align}$ Jacky it's just $$\begin{align}
y' = t+y \ \ \implies \ \ y(t) = ce^{t}-t-1.
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Isham $y_{0} + 1$ is still just a constant. $(y_{0} + 1)e^{t} - t - 1$ is only the solution of the ODE with the initial contion $y(0)=y_{0}$. $y_{0} + 1$ can be treated as if it were a constant $c$.

Comment: ok thanks Eliot